# ODOO8 - Add a line containing the product long description under eache product line

Tags: odoo-8, qweb, purchase-order

I am not a QWEB specialist and I try to change the standard purchase order by adding a line containing the long product description (Precise description) under each product line.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

L. Adam